# Is there option to build dacpac only when there are changes?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 to build sql project.

The issue is that building and deploying the dacpac to our database takes up most of our deployment time, when a lot of times, there are no changes to the database.

Is it possible to not have the dacpac build when there are no changes to the database?

Comment: Why are you building the project if there are no changes?

Comment: I'm building solution, which the sql is part of it. I can't avoid it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that there is already suggestion for this as a feature, which is pending for votes:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/42925275-make-sqlpackage-dacpac-deterministic

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use Azure Devops for dacpac CI/CD.
In that case your effort would be minimal.

It's quite wide to describe.

Take a look at this video for a general idea:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4N_fv6d3KQY